# Is looking at a computer screen all that bad for you?

Tags: technology, computers

As you've all heard around on the internet looking at a screen is bad and awful for you, however, is there any proof that screens and **only** screens are the cause of these health issues?

[This article by the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/how-bad-for-your-eyes-are-computer-screens/2014/01/17/985b90cc-7c98-11e3-93c1-0e888170b723_story.html?utm_term=.b85460a6f6d6) agrees that some may be caused by reading too, but also goes on to claim that phones and such also cause stress to the eye, but doesn't refer this to also being close to reading a book.

Most physical issues can also be caused by simply sitting down, and many of the vision issues (such as dry/irritated eyes) can also be caused by reading for a long time.

Simply put, is there anything that screens do to your visual/mental health that aren't caused by other things you may do, such as reading or just sitting down?

Comment: @sumelic there are various guides I looked up (attempting to disprove this) but got a mixed result, I shall edit the post and add some.

Comment: I don't think it can be answered for *screens* in general, there are issues related to specific technologies, like eg LCD.

Comment: Are you asking about something in the article? Include the relevant quote please. If you're not, then you're still missing a notable claim.

Comment: We are looking for a specific claim. "All that bad for you" isn't specific enough. You try to rule out other causes (sitting, reading) but it isn't clear that the original claimants aren't including those effects in their claims. The article is paywalled, or I would have looked though and tried to find out for you and quoted it.